# SQL MERGE INSERT INTO not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm having trouble with a MERGE statement in SQL. I tried following guides by Microsoft but with no great success.

I want the code to update any rows it finds are matched and insert the non-matched rows into a different table.

I have been using the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NotMatched
(ID INT , Year INT, Month INT, Quantity INT,   
 CONSTRAINT PK_Matched PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID));  
GO  

CREATE TABLE dbo.Updated
(ID INT , Year INT, Month INT, Quantity INT,   
 CONSTRAINT PK_Updated PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID));  
GO  

CREATE TABLE dbo.Staging
(ID INT , Year INT, Month INT, Quantity INT,   
 CONSTRAINT PK_Staging PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID));  
GO  

MERGE INTO dbo.Updated AS Target  
USING (SELECT ID, Year, Month, Quantity  
        FROM dbo.Staging AS stg) AS Source (ID, Year, Month, Quantity)  
 ON Target.ID = Source.ID  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET Target.Year = Source.Year, Target.Month = Source.Month, 
Target.Quantity = Source.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (ID, Year, Month, Quantity) VALUES (Source.ID, Source.Year, Source.Month, Source.Quantity)  
OUTPUT $action INTO dbo.NotMatched (ID, Year, Month, Quantity);
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I cannot see any obvious errors, if anyone can provide me with some help that would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Kriss

Comment: your code is incorrect, give a real example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$action` ? what does this do ?

should be

```
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Year, inserted.Month, inserted.Quantity
INTO dbo.NotMatched (ID, Year, Month, Quantity);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was using the examples off https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and they all contain the $action. Assumed it was required. Thanks again!

Comment: $action - normal value for MERGE. "$action INTO dbo.NotMatched (ID, Year, Month, Quantity);"  this incorrect

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation you cite in the comments:

```
$action is a column of type nvarchar(10) that returns one of three values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE', according to the action that was performed on that row.
```

Thus, this line:

```
OUTPUT $action INTO dbo.NotMatched (ID, Year, Month, Quantity);
```

is incorrect, because it has only one `nvarchar(10)` input, but you're trying to insert four columns.

In each case in the samples where `$action` is used, it is being inserted into a column designed for a string describing the action.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.